# From a video file (.mp4) to live video (usbcamera) - OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video, camera, raspberry-pi

Recenty I made a proyect with OpenCV, dectects cars, that inputs video file and output another video file.

I want, with the help of a raspberry pi or similar, turn the input video(mp4) to a live webcam input(usb camera or similar), and output the video processed in livetime to my screen, to basicly mount a rasppbery pi (or similar) to my car with a camera, and output in live the detection in a screen.

How to do that? any documentation?

Comment: what is the actual question? please, be more specific

Comment: Now I input a .mp4 file, and output .mp4 processed file. I want to turn that file (edit my code)  to  input LIVE from a camera, and output LIVE to a screen, to mount my system to my car. How to do that? any documentation?

Comment: Live is different then non live.  Encoding and processing tend to be really different.

Comment: Tensor flow object detection API with cam in will work? Dunno if raspberry pi will work here.